# Getting "Linq is not a member of NHibernate.ISession" error when implementing Linq to NHibernate

Tags: .net, vb.net, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm struggling with getting Linq To NHibernate to work. I have referenced NHibernate, NHibernate.Linq and NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle . Also I have all other dependencies in the same folder.

Code / Error message:

```
 Public Function GetProjectsByName(ByVal ProjectName As String) As List(Of Project)

    Return (From x In _session.Linq(Of Project)() Where x.Name.Equals(Project))

 End Function
```

> "Linq is not a member of NHibernate.ISession"

... tells me that the LINQ extensions aren't loaded. Using NHibernate.Linq seems to be made in a way that it's incredibly easy to use, hence there are no tutorials on how to set it up. (Or at least I couldn't find any).

Do you have any idea, what I could be missing?

**UPDATE:**
References of Data Access Layer

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose it is silly to ask, but you have Imported the namespace ?

Comment: Yes, currently I have Imports statements for NHibernate, NHibernate.Linq, System.Linq and my Entities project.

Comment: Have you referenced the appropiate .dll files? I forgot to do that with C#, NHibernate and VS2010

Comment: Here, I added a screenshot of my references to my post. Did you use Castle or LinFu?

Comment: I had used Castle, i am assuming _session is an ISession object, has it been instantiated? I have absolutely no experience in VB.NET just trying to help out from a C# point of view

Comment: Yeah, the ISession object is fine. I can pull data via ICriteria API without problems. Is there anything else besides referencing the NHibernate.Linq.dll and importing it in order to update a running NHibernate-powered project to a Linq-to-NHibernate-enabled one?

Comment: Where exactly did you get NHibernate.Linq from (ie what version it is) ?

Comment: NHibernate.Linq-1.0.0.GA-bin.zip (version is 1.1.0.1001) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/
 -- I also tried the latest code from the SVN repository, but after the build: same result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue resolved! It was indeed due to different versions of assemblies, like Tomas Pajonk suggested.

The following assembly versions work together:

- NHibernate 2.1.0.4000
- NHibernate.Linq 1.0.0.4000
- Castle.Core 1.1.0.0
- Castle.DynamicProxy2 2.0.3.0 (2.0.3.4333)
- Iesi.Collections 1.0.1.0
- log4net 1.2.10.0
- NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle 2.1.0.4000
- Antlr3.Runtime 3.1.0.39271

Thanks to everybody who helped!

Comment: I am glad you sorted it out. Sometimes so many helper libraries make one's head spin.

Comment: @motto: you also need NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll and Antlr3.Runtime.dll